# Passing JSON data from JS to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, json, phpmailer, html2pdf

Looked for various solutions but haven't found one yet.
I'm stuck with the following bit of code and my hunch is that the jsondata arriving to the hphp script is empty, but I am clueless as to how to debug as this script is run in the background only.

Javascript:

```
 var pdfdata = {};
    
function SendMail(){
    let el = document.getElementById('content');
    let el2 = document.getElementById("tilaus");
    let opt = {
        margin:       1,
        filename:     'myfile.pdf',
        image:        { type: 'jpeg', quality: 0.98 },
        html2canvas:  { scale: 2 },
        jsPDF:        { unit: 'mm', format: 'A4', orientation: 'portrait' }
    };
    
    html2pdf().set( opt ).from( el ).toPdf().output('datauristring').then(function( pdfAsString ) {
        pdfdata["tilaus"] = {
            'fileDataURI': pdfAsString,
    
        };
        //$.post( "../Laskuri/php/send_script.php", data);
    } );
    html2pdf().set( opt ).from( el2 ).toPdf().output('datauristring').then(function( pdfAsString ) {
          pdfdata["tilausvahvistus"] = {
             'fileDataURI2': pdfAsString,
    
         };
     } );
    var jsondata = JSON.stringify(pdfdata);
    console.log( JSON.stringify(pdfdata, null, "    ") );
    $.post( "../Laskuri/php/send_script.php", jsondata);
    }
```

And then on the PHP side:

```
<?php 
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require './src/Exception.php';
require './src/PHPMailer.php';
        $array = json_decode($_POST["jsondata"],true);
            $mail = new PHPMailer;
            $mail->setFrom( 'asiakas@kajonsteel.fi', 'website' );
            $mail->addAddress( 'myynti@kajonsteel.fi', 'Kajon Steel Oy' );
            $mail->Subject  = 'Tilaus';
            $mail->Body     = 'Kiitos tilauksesta. Liitteenä tilausvahvistus ja tilaus.';

            $pdfdoc         = $array->tilaus->fileDataURI;
            $b64file        = trim( str_replace( 'data:application/pdf;base64,', '', $pdfdoc ) );
            $b64file        = str_replace( ' ', '+', $b64file );
            $decoded_pdf    = base64_decode( $b64file );
    
            $pdfdoc2         = $array->tilausvahvistus->fileDataURI2; 
            $b64file2        = trim( str_replace( 'data:application/pdf;base64,', '', $pdfdoc2 ) );
            $b64file2        = str_replace( ' ', '+', $b64file2 );
            $decoded_pdf2    = base64_decode( $b64file2 );

            $mail->addStringAttachment($decoded_pdf2, "tilausvahvistus.pdf");
        $mail->addStringAttachment($decoded_pdf, "tilaus.pdf");
            $mail->isHTML( true );
            $mail->send();
?>
```

Am I accessing the jsondata correctly?
console.log gives an empty set first time round, but if I click the button that activates sendMail() again then console.log does show that is filled correctly (and this second email has corrupted pdf's as well).

Comment: The code fails to send the data to the server. jQuery post method sends the data using application/x-www-form-urlencoded enc type. That means, that the JSON string you've send to your server is treated as a form field name on the server, but no data in the field. If you want to read a single value from `$_POST`, you've to send that value: `const data = 'jsondata=' + jsondata;`, and pass `data` instead of `pdfdata`. That way your server can find `$_POST["jsondata"]` and decode it correctly.

Comment: Hi! I think you meant the following? 
`var jsondata = JSON.stringify(pdfdata);`
const data = 'jsondata=' + jsondata;
$.post( "../Laskuri/php/send_script.php", data);`

Comment: Yep, exactly. That way the data format send to the server will be correct. You might also want to encode the data, `'jsondata=' + encodeURIComponent(jsondata);` does that.

Comment: The pdf files are still showing as corrupted though. Is my way of accessing the jsondata correct? pdfdata is an object of objects basically.

Comment: I'm not familiar with html2pdf, so I can't say. If the encoding the data doesn't fix the issue, you've to wait untill someone knowing html2pdf visits the question.

Comment: Thanks anyway. Any suggestions as to how to debug this php script that runs on the backend? Haven't done that much php related and clueless as to how to get a variable value to show up on a backend running script... Would love to see how the data looks like once brought in to the server side.

Comment: You can see the data on the browser too. Open the Network tab of the DevTools, make the request on the page, and you can see the all the information of the request on the Network tab.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to use a workaround to get this fixed.
The issue I was experiencing was that I was calling the same php script twice, posting a value each time.
I fixed this by starting session variables and waiting for both of them to "fill up" before sending the email.

JS:

```
function SendMail(){

let el = document.getElementById('content');
let el2 = document.getElementById("tilaus");
let opt = {
    margin:       1,
    filename:     'myfile.pdf',
    image:        { type: 'jpeg', quality: 0.98 },
    html2canvas:  { scale: 2 },
    jsPDF:        { unit: 'mm', format: 'A4', orientation: 'portrait' }
};

html2pdf().set( opt ).from( el ).toPdf().output('datauristring').then(function( pdfAsString ) {
    //pdfdata.tilaus = {
    let data={
        'fileDataURI': pdfAsString,

    };
    $.post( "../Laskuri/php/send_script.php", data);
} );
html2pdf().set( opt ).from( el2 ).toPdf().output('datauristring').then(function( pdfAsString ) {
      let data = {
         'fileDataURI2': pdfAsString,
     };
     $.post( "../Laskuri/php/send_script.php", data);
 } );


}
```

PHP:

```
<?php 
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
require './src/Exception.php';
require './src/PHPMailer.php';
session_start();
            $mail = new PHPMailer;
            $mail->setFrom( 'asiakas@kajonsteel.fi', 'website' );
            $mail->addAddress( 'myynti@kajonsteel.fi', 'Kajon Steel Oy' );
            $mail->Subject  = 'Tilaus';
            $mail->Body     = 'Kiitos tilauksesta. Liitteenä tilausvahvistus ja tilaus.';

        if(isset($_POST["fileDataURI"])){
        $_SESSION["fileDataURI"] = $_POST["fileDataURI"];
        }
        $pdfdoc = $_SESSION["fileDataURI"];
            $b64file        = trim( str_replace( 'data:application/pdf;base64,', '', $pdfdoc ) );
            $b64file        = str_replace( ' ', '+', $b64file );
            $decoded_pdf    = base64_decode( $b64file );

        if(isset($_POST["fileDataURI2"])){
        $_SESSION["fileDataURI2"] = $_POST["fileDataURI2"];
        }
        $pdfdoc2 = $_SESSION["fileDataURI2"];   
            $b64file2        = trim( str_replace( 'data:application/pdf;base64,', '', $pdfdoc2 ) );
            $b64file2        = str_replace( ' ', '+', $b64file2 );
            $decoded_pdf2    = base64_decode( $b64file2 );
            $mail->addStringAttachment($decoded_pdf2, "tilausvahvistus.pdf");
        $mail->addStringAttachment($decoded_pdf, "tilaus.pdf");
            $mail->isHTML( true );
            if(!empty($decoded_pdf) and !empty($decoded_pdf2)){ 
        $mail->send();
        session_destroy();
        }
?>
```